# requestFeature() must be called before adding error

Tags: android, android-dialog

This one I do not understand at all, I am trying to display a custom dialog with no title like this

```
d.setContentView(R.layout.incident_dialog_layout);
d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

doing this gives me an error

```
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:215)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.app.Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Dialog.java:1031)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at ecm2.android.MainActivity.createNewDialog(MainActivity.java:1121)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at ecm2.android.MainActivity$ListViews.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:614)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-25 11:56:23.737: E/AndroidRuntime(15680):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ok that simple enough just change where the request is. So I then change it to this

```
d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
d.setContentView(R.layout.incident_dialog_layout);
```

dialog works until I start a new activity when I go back and click on the item that creates the dialog I get this error

```
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:215)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.app.Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Dialog.java:1031)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at ecm2.android.MainActivity.createNewDialog(MainActivity.java:1120)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at ecm2.android.MainActivity$ListViews.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:614)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-25 11:51:19.182: E/AndroidRuntime(15376):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

so what does it want me to do then since I cant have it after I set the content nore can I have it before I sent the content?????

Comment: Is that code set in onCreate() method?

Comment: no it is not, it is in a method that creates a couple different dialog's based on the information passed in, basically its a dialog that is displayed via a list item click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that error because the second time you set the dialog layout(this is, when you come back from the second activity), you already have content in your screen.

So, calling requestWindowFeature this second time causes the error.

You'll have to move that statement to onCreate() method, hence only one time is called requestFeature, ensuring no content is added before its call.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the second comment on the question, I would guess that you are calling requestFeature() in the onStart or onResume methods.

requestFeature, as well as setContentView, should called in onCreate(). if you do it anywhere else it will get called again and cause your app to throw an error.